# How to use Django's DetailView (or some built-in view class) for a home page?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views, detailview

I'm building an app in Django and I would like to set up a home page for authenticated users.

I thought it was best to use de built-in [`generic.DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) for this, given that the details I want to show in the page are those of the identified user. The thing is, this class needs to receive the id of the target entity through the URL as a decimal *pk* argument. However, the information about the entity, is in `request.user`, and I would like to avoid repeating that information so as not to show my user ids in the urls.

I would imagine that getting the `request` within the [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method would do the trick, but it does not take arguments.

Is this possible? Is this a good idea? Are there any alternatives that I may be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DetailView` only needs the `pk` or `slug` to fetch the object. If you override `get_object` then it is not required. In the `get_object` method, you can access the user with `self.request.user`.

Finally, if your view uses the logged in user, then you can use the `LoginRequiredMixin` to ensure that only logged in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class MyDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    ...
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```